# how to pass multiple bundles from an activity/class through multiple successive classes so the data ends up at a final class?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, bundle

how to pass multiple bundles from an activity/class through multiple successive classes to all end up at a final activity (final activity = email client from android app)? I was able to pass one bundle of strings from one activity/class to the immediate following final activity /class (the in-app email client) ?  can you point me to a good resource?

I was able to pass 1 bundle of strings like this:

```
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);

    //create a bundle object to store
    //the bundle we added to the intent
    Bundle bundle1=getIntent().getExtras();

    //get the values out by key
    String Medicx1=bundle1.getString("Medicx1");
    String Medicx2=bundle1.getString("Medicx2");
    String Medicx3=bundle1.getString("Medicx3");
    String Medicx4=bundle1.getString("Medicx4");
    String Medicx5=bundle1.getString("Medicx5");
    String Medicx6=bundle1.getString("Medicx6");


    //get the textview controls
    EditText medication1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    //set the text values of the text controls
    medication1.setText("To whom it may concern \n\n " +
            "On this trip, different travelers will be taking the following medications: \n \n"+
            "-"+ Medicx1 + "\n \n" +
            "-"+ Medicx2 + "\n \n" +
            "-"+ Medicx3 + "\n \n" +
            "-"+ Medicx4 + "\n \n" +
            "-"+ Medicx5 + "\n \n" +
            "-"+ Medicx6 + "\n \n" +
            "i would like you to know this before the trip");
```

*** I successfully got the above code to work because this information comes from the immediately previous class/activity***

but i want more data, from classes that are even farther away, to show up also in the final activity/class.

Comment: you can create  a class with static variables and store values in that variables

Comment: Thank you deepakjohn141  ... i will begin by researching that !

Comment: Hi deepakJohn141, can you please point me in the direction where i can learn about creating a class with static variables that would store such values?

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a local database (SQLite) to store and retrieve things to use throughout the classes or you can create a class that would store all the data and have an instance of that class live in an interface that you would implement on all those classes.